# When I changed even position image in listView then images of all even listView become same in android Java. Same with odd position images

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, imageview

I want to do that If the image on listView clicks then audio plays and the icon change. I write code for both correctly but face one issue in changing images. If I clicked on the position one image then the position image changed successfully but somehow the images of an odd number of listview also change to position 1 When I click on the position 2 image the position image changed but with that, all even number positions changed.

**What I want**
When I click on position one image only that image of list view changes and the other will remain the same.

```
public class AllAudioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
   private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<VerseData> arrayList;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Boolean flag = true;
    int first =-1;
    ImageView previous;
    


    public AllAudioAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<VerseData> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
      public TextView number, eng_text, arabic_text;
      public ImageView ivPlay;
      public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);

            viewHolder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);

            viewHolder.arabic_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arabic_text);

            viewHolder.eng_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng_text);


            viewHolder.ivPlay = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.play_pic);

            viewHolder.relativeLayout =(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relative);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        VerseData verseData = arrayList.get(position);

        viewHolder.number.setText(verseData.getNumber());
        viewHolder.arabic_text.setText(verseData.getArabic());
        viewHolder.eng_text.setText(verseData.getEnglish());

        // play music
        viewHolder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(flag ){
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, verseData.getAudio());
                    flag = false;
                }
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    if(first== position)
                    flag= true;
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }
                if(first!= position)
                {
                    if(first!=-1)
                    {
                        differentPosition();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, verseData.getAudio());
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }
                previous = viewHolder.ivPlay;
                first = position;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public void showToaster(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(context,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void differentPosition()
    {
        previous.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the *ViewHolder* pattern, where instead of every item in the list having its own `View`, you have a small pool of them which get *reused*. When an item scrolls out of view, its `ViewHolder` can be used to display another item that's scrolling into view.

So that new item gets an old `ViewHolder`, which was used to display some other item, and has all its data displayed - text, images, whatever. You need to *update* all that, so it's displaying the correct data for the *new* item - which is what you're doing in `getView`, after the `if` section that creates a new `ViewHolder` if the pool needs another one.

---

It sounds like your pool has **2** `ViewHolder`s, *A* and *B*. So the first item in your list uses VH *A*, the second uses *B*, the third uses *A* again, the fourth *B*, and so on.

When you click the first item, which is displayed in *ViewHolder A*, the click listener fires, and does this (other stuff removed):

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
} else {
    viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
}
```

So *ViewHolder A updates its image* when you click. But remember, *that ViewHolder gets reused* so every item using *A* will show that image! The result is that the image *depends on which ViewHolder the item happens to display in*, not *the item itself*.

---

So you need to store some playing/stopped state *for the item*, and make the click listener *update that*. And when you set up the `ViewHolder` to display an item's details, text etc, *that's where you set the play/stop image* as appropriate.

Assuming there's only one item that can play at a time, you could just hold a "now playing" value:

```
// store the playing item (if any) in the top level of your adapter
VerseData nowPlaying = null;
```

In `getView()`, use `nowPlaying` to decide which icon to display

```
VerseData verseData = arrayList.get(position);
viewHolder.number.setText(verseData.getNumber());
...
if (verseData.equals(nowPlaying)) {
    viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
} else {
    // you -always- have to explicitly set the data -either way-,
    // so it always shows the correct image - if it was play before, this will fix it
    viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
}
```

And then update the playing item in your click listener

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    // stopping the playing item - clear the "now playing" value
    nowPlaying = null
} else {
    // otherwise set it to this item - this means any old "now playing" value
    // will be replaced
    nowPlaying = verseData
}
// since something's changed, items will need to refresh (so they can update their
// displays with the code in getView(), including displaying the correct image)
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

That's the basics, you'll have to fit that in with the rest of your code, but hopefully it makes sense! The playing state is part of your *data*, it's something associated with your *items*. `ViewHolder`s are temporary and you shouldn't try to store item state in them (like setting an icon) because they're reused for different items, so they eithr get wiped clean, or show old state that's incorrect for the item it's displaying.

Btw, a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview) is the modern way to do this *ViewHolder pattern*, and it's easier to work with - you have separate methods for creating a new VH, and setting its data for an item. Just in case you need to do this in future!